# ¿Cuál es la mejor traducción para "wearable" en este texto?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones, sinónimos

Me han mandado una pregunta con respecto al siguiente artículo en inglés: [Stretchable biofuel cells extract energy from sweat to power wearable devices](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2017/08/170822092209.htm).

La pregunta consta de la palabra "wearable", además de que en ese texto tanto su título como el cuerpo ya aparece varias veces el término "wearable". La pregunta que está en español ha traducido "wearable" como **"usable"**.

Mi pregunta es, **¿es correcto utilizar la traducción "es usable" en vez de que "wearable" signifique "portátil"?** ¿O ambas formas son correctas?

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Usable* no me parece correcto en absoluto porque simplemente significa *capaz de ser usado*, pero ojo: *wearable* no significa *portátil*, aunque es algo que se suele sobreentender.

Las opciones más adecuadas son tanto tecnología **vestible**, tecnología **ponible** o tecnología **llevable**, con las primeras dos gozando de más uso y siendo más exacta en su traducción.  Cada una de las tres opciones tienen el [sí de la RAE](https://twitter.com/raeinforma/status/438658019355009024), y las primeras [lo tienen de Fundéu](https://twitter.com/fundeu/status/420848095572684801).

En una hila en Google+, Fundéu [argumenta por *ponible*](https://plus.google.com/108243596952318544013/posts/8uAnZ2kG83i) como más genérico, diciendo que

> Pensamos en vestible, pero ¿las gafas, por ejemplo, se visten? Por otro lado, llevable no tiene el matiz de 'llevar puesto', solo indica que se puede llevar. Saludos.

Al final de cuentas, creo que tenemos una situación en la que por un solo término génerico inglés, es necesario emplear una abanica de palabras, según cada contexto.  Por ejemplo, la tecnología del enlace me parece incluso más adecuada la palabra «aplicable», porque es como una película que —esperen señoras y señores— se aplica a la piel.  Para un término sumamente génerico, creo que se podría optar por «accesorios inteligentes» aunque tal vez englobe un pelín más de lo que engloba el correspondiente término inglés.

Comment: ¡Gracias! La pregunta utiliza "usable", tampoco me parece acertado... ¿Qué hay de "portátil"? ¿Es "más" o "menos" que "vestible"?

Comment: Portátil solo significa que es capaz de ser portado (y sería la traducción precisa para el inglés *portable*). Un móvil es portátil, sin duda, pero no lo veo muy vestible, ya que no es ninguna sustitución por ropa.  Pero un reloj inteligente sí es vestible sin duda (la raíz de *wearable* — *wear* — es *vestir* en castellano)

Answer (score 5):

La Fundéu [sugiere *ponible*](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/tecnologia-ponible-mejor-que-wearable-technology/), que me parece un término muy exacto.

> Para referirse a la tecnología que incorporan estos dispositivos, prendas y complementos lo más adecuado es recurrir al adjetivo **ponible**, formación regular a partir del verbo poner, que alude al hecho de que estos objetos tecnológicos se pueden llevar puestos.

Comment: ¿Podrías expandir un poco la respuesta introduciendo algo del texto del artículo que enlazas? Incluso se puede referenciar el DLE, que tiene entrada para esta palabra: https://dle.rae.es/?id=TdvM5EK

Comment: Ah, claro. Ponible.  También gozo de mucho uso.

Comment: Wow, no sabía que existía esa página, ¡gracias! Sin embargo, aquí en Argentina no solemos decir *tecnología ponible*, sino que lo utilizamos más para prendas, como bien enlazó @fedorqui.